# Adding Suffixes to labels

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have some labels that have a mathematical formula attached to them and i was wondering how you add a suffix to them. I am aware of one way to add prefixes

```
LblUsername.Text = "Welcome " & TxtUsername.Text
```

I have tried to add the suffix like this

```
Label1.Text = ((2 * TextBox1.Text * 0.707106781) / 9.8) & "Seconds"
```

But to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hey, Label1.Text = ((2 * TextBox1.Text * 0.707106781) / 9.8) & "Seconds" is working for me. Only in the cases when i enter numeric value. You need to give more details on your situation. like what error (if any) are you getting.

Comment: @Harsh the automatic conversion text to number is done more or less OK, but it is always good to rely on proper types. More specifically in this case, you should be accounting for double/float, instead of for integer, in order to make sure that the calculations are performed rightly.

Comment: Yes i totally agree with you. But the issue the user is facing is not clear. I meant to say that this works in certain situation and conversion is a must according to the requirement. But we don't have enough info on what the real problem is.

Comment: @Harsh I know that is not clear, but he/she is of this kind of OPs... I prefer to ask something and see his/her behaviour before going ahead with an answer. There are people with serious problems keen on solving them and there are other people with... I don't know... too much free time, I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to integer before calculating.

```
Label1.Text = ((2 * Ctype(TextBox1.Text, integer) * 0.707106781) / 9.8).ToString & "Seconds"
```

Comment: Harsh your code did not work for me. I do not experience an error the suffix just does not display. only numbers are ever entered. could it have something to do with  my rounding fuction    `Label1.Text = Math.Round(Val(Label1.Text), 2)`

Comment: Can you show some more code or tell us what are you trying to achieve. Whatever issue you are facing should not be there. This means there is some problem in the approach. show us some more code.

Comment: Private Sub TxtName_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                              ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown


        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            Label1.Text = ((2 * CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer) * 0.707106781) / 9.8).ToString & "Seconds"
            Label1.Text = Math.Round(Val(Label1.Text), 2)

            Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text * Label1.Text * 0.707106781
            Label2.Text = FormatNumber(Label2.Text, 2)

        End If

    End Sub